# How can I capture & track an AdWords user from outside of the browser?

Tags: c#, cookies, web, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I have a PC (Windows, OSX, Linux) video game on the Steam marketplace and an extremely common problem for us developers is that there is no way to find out if a user who clicked on our game through our AdWords campaign, has actually bought it. Steam provides some analytics tracking up until our game page, but it falls into a black box after that.

I have all the power in the world once the user opens our game, so my thought here is that surely we can find the AdWords tracking ID/cookie and manually POST that to our Google Analytics platform?

I suppose step 1 is - How do we make our AdWords campaign leave a long lasting cookie/tracking ID somewhere?
Step 2 - How do I find it and POST it?

Answer (score 0):

For GA to know if someone bought your product on a third party marketplace website, it is necessary for you to place a piece of code on their order confirmation page, but without that, measuring conversions, may not be remotely possible. 
As an example, if you listed your product on Amazon marketplace, and you ran an adwords campaign for the product, while amazon has their SEM. Adwords catches this redundancy, and it may drop your campaign since amazon is the original website running their own SEM and campaigns.